# Overriding preventDefault() in the JavaScript module pattern

Tags: javascript, singleton, preventdefault

I'm using the singleton pattern to create a form processing script...

I don't want to post all the code up but the first method uses preventDefault:

```
//public methods
    handleSubmit: function (e) {

        //prevent the default submission process
        e.preventDefault();

},
```

the preventDafault does what it should which is to hijack the form to stop server-side processing.

Then I have created validation rules... and if all validation rules are passed it finishes off with this method:

```
validData: function (error) {
        if (error.length === 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            // If there are errors in the form then run alert message
            alert(error);
        }

    },
```

That being that if there are no errors then the server-side script processes the form and the item is added to the database (I'm not using AJAX because I have an issue with images)

However, the return true doesn't work here... and I don't know why, but I'm sure there is a very simple reason for it

Comment: Can't you just programmatically trigger a submit instead of returning true? Once you have prevented default I don't think returning true does anything anymore. `.submit()`

Comment: What is it that you expect the `true` return value to do?

Answer (score 0):

can you skip the preventDefault function and just do something like this?

```
var hasErrors = false;
    if(myLogicHasErrors){
        hasErrors = true;
    }
    if(hasErrors) return false;
```

It will just prevent form submission without prevent default unless your validation checks go through.

Comment: okay worked it out. instead of "return false" I used "return CS.AddNode.Form.submit():" edit: no it doesn't

Comment: right finally found out a way. I placed "return false" into the end of every single method until after errors equalled 0 in the final method and then I ran "return CS.AddNode.Form.submit();"

Comment: hmmmm... not sure you need to `return CS.AddNode.Form.submit();`in your case. I imagine you don't need the return because you are just telling the form to submit().